# Can't find Android Manifest in flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest, flutter2.0

Where do I find the android manifest file in Flutter 2.2, it's not under its typical location
[Not here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9taVZ.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

android manifest is located in your projects android/app/src/main/,

if it is not there then just simply run `flutter create .`  in your project root directory,

this will create it,

Comment: what should happen after that

Comment: it will create all auto generated files if any i deleted by mistakenly

Comment: please share output for flutter doctor ,

Answer (score 0):

You can see here the Flutter Project structure.

> In the screen shot you can see the project structure and easily find the manifest file. Path : Flutter_Project/android/app/src/main

[Screen Shot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dd9JY.png)

Comment: it is not there